# MojoExecutionException when trying to profile netbeans project

Tags: java, netbeans

There's about a million bug reports regarding the issue on NetBeans bug tracker but none of them brought me a resolution.

The issue is that when I try to profile my program, like this:

[image: image description]

I get this:

```
cd C:\MYSELF\programing\java\AutoCall\AutoClient; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_31" cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Users\\Jakub\\AppData\\Roaming\\NetBeans\\7.4\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -Dexec.args=\"-agentpath:C:/Users/Jakub/AppData/Roaming/NetBeans/7.4/lib/deployed/jdk16/windows-amd64/profilerinterface.dll=C:\\Users\\Jakub\\AppData\\Roaming\\NetBeans\\7.4\\lib,5140,10 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\\MYSELF\\programing\\java\\AutoCall\\AutoClient\\nbproject\\private\\profiler  -classpath %classpath cz.autoclient.Main\" -Dexec.executable=\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_31\\bin\\java.exe\" -DnetbeansProjectMappings= -Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\\Users\\Jakub\\AppData\\Roaming\\NetBeans\\7.4\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec\""
Running NetBeans Compile On Save execution. Phase execution is skipped and output directories of dependency projects (with Compile on Save turned on) will be used instead of their jar artifacts.
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building Auto Client 3.0
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ autoclient ---
Profiler Agent: Waiting for connection on port 5140, timeout 10 seconds (Protocol version: 14)
Profiler Agent Error: Timed out trying to establish connection with client
Profiler Agent: Initializing...
Profiler Agent: Options: >C:\Users\Jakub\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.4\lib,5140,10<
Profiler Agent: Initialized successfully
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 12.012s
Finished at: Sun Jan 03 20:57:36 CET 2016
Final Memory: 5M/75M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project autoclient: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: -1 (Exit value: -1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

This error seems to happen at random - I had several successful profiling sessions, then it happened again.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, when I tryed to start the netbeans profile to analyze memory, I got the follow message:

Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project saf-desktop: The parameters 'executable' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]

So, instead to run de profile mode, I started the application normally and then, I atached the profile mode in the currenty runnig main application.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the timeout. Run netbeans with the following argument:

> netbeans64.exe -J-Dprofiler.agent.connect.timeout=60

See https://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/entry/tweaking_profiler_timeouts